# What does this ‘feeling loads of stuff out’ mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> In addition, Healy discussed working with Jack Antonoff on Being Funny in a Foreign Language:
> I love Jack’s work, and those Lana [Del Rey] records, in particular, like, some of my favorite stuff. So we were talking about that. We became friends talking about production and what I was doing and what he was wanting to do and what I was wanting to do. And then I kind of just thought, “Well, this is like a really nice new energy.” I don’t… because we are so closed, me and George [Daniel], we’ve always been so closed. “Why don’t you like come down to the studio and see what happens?” And then he did. And, then, ever since, we were just great, great friends.

> He’s so good. What he does is identifies what an artist is really good at or where the truth is coming from. And it’s a bit like, if you think of like a great comedian, the language of like sense of humor, they can sense where the humor is in the situation. Jack’s like, he’s like me, you know what I mean? He’s like culture vulture, he’s like full of references. He knows his shit, man. He understands what artists need at any given moment. And it happened very, very naturally.  And I think that **we were just feeling loads of stuff out.** And all these things just kind of came together. Yeah, and me and Jack were just like talking about music and then those conversations, me, Jack, and George. And then those conversations became about a 1975 record that felt more live. And then I was a bit like, “Well, why are we talking about this? Why don’t we just do this?”

Hello everyone. I need native speakers help. What does **’we were just feeling loads of stuff out.’** mean?
To feel out means trying to discover something carefully or indirectly. But I still can’t get what the sentence means here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They were trying out lots of ideas. To feel an idea out is to 'try it out', or tentatively explore it.

> feel out
>
> 1. To carefully and cautiously try to gain knowledge of something. A noun or pronoun can be used between "feel" and "out."

[Feel Out (The Free Dictionary)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/feel+out)

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation